# Using \nearrow and \searrow to separate an equation in two alternatives

Tags: equations, arrows, arrays

I'm tryin' to write the solution of an equation with two possible solutions, as `x(ax-a+1)=0`. I'm using `\nearrow` and `\searrow` with an array but I don't get it fits right. This is the code:

```
$\rightarrow x(ax-a+1)=0\begin{array}{ll}
 & {\color{red}{\color{red}x=0}}\\
\nearrow\\
\searrow & ax-a+1=0\rightarrow x=\dfrac{a-1}{a}\rightarrow{\color{red}{\color{red}x=1-\dfrac{1}{a}}}
\end{array}$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of fixing your approach, I just show two other possibilities which I would prefer here.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \[\rightarrow x(ax-a+1)=0\rightarrow\begin{dcases}
    {\color{red}x=0}\\
    ax-a+1=0\rightarrow x=\frac{a-1}{a}\rightarrow{\color{red}x=1-\frac{1}{a}}
    \end{dcases}\]

    \[\begin{tikzcd}[%
    ,row sep={10,between origins}, column sep=15
    ,every arrow/.append style={start anchor=east, end anchor=west}
    ,/tikz/column 2/.append style={anchor=base west}
    ]
    & \color{red}x=0\\
    \rightarrow x(ax-a+1)=0 \arrow{ur}\arrow{dr} & \\
    & ax-a+1=0\rightarrow x=\dfrac{a-1}{a}\rightarrow{\color{red}x=1-\dfrac{1}{a}}
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\rightarrow` in front of the big brace is not really needed, though.

If you want to separate the arrows in my second example, you can do something like `\arrow[shorten <= 1mm]{ur}\arrow[shorten <= 1mm]{dr}` or you add some `yshift` to their start anchors.

Answer (score 3):

To show how you can adapt your approach, I suggest putting the arrows on the same rows as the sequences they point to and shifting them vertically by `1ex`.  A uniform appearance will be given by adding an appropriate phantom to the first row to give it the same proportions as the second.  You can also reduce the space between the array columns with an `@{...}` construction.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath}

\begin{document}

$
\rightarrow x(ax-a+1)=0
  \begin{array}{l@{\ }l}
    \raisebox{-1ex}{$\nearrow$} &{\color{red}{\color{red}x=0}}
                                  \vphantom{\dfrac1a}\\
    \raisebox{1ex}{$\searrow$}  &ax-a+1=0
                                  \rightarrow x=\dfrac{a-1}{a}
                                  \rightarrow {\color{red}x=1-\dfrac{1}{a}}
  \end{array}
$

\end{document}
```